# Elasticsearch - Query based on text length

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, filter

I'm using the official Elasticsearch NodeJS client library, to query the following index structure:

```
{
  "_index": "articles",
  "_type": "context",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "article": "this is a paragraph",
    "topic": "topic A"
  }
}

{
  "_index": "articles",
  "_type": "context",
  "_id": "2",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "article": "this is a paragraph this is a paragraph this is a paragraph",
    "topic": "topic B"
  }
}
```

I would like to query my index using the term *"this is a paragraph"* and boost the result with the most similar text length, IE: **document _id:1**

Can I do this without re-indexing and adding a field to my index ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786713/elasticsearch-query-filter-for-word-count))?

Comment: If you cannot the change the mapping or do a re-indexing then probably Groovy scripts at query time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to elasticsearch... Colors you elaborate.

Comment: Hm... let me post a sample query as an example...

Comment: Do you have a more elaborate example on what you are trying to achieve and what "most similar text length" means?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, basically I want to match articles that have similar content and are similar in word count

Comment: "similar" is a broad term when it comes to Elasticsearch. "similar" can also mean fuzzy search for example, or number of terms to match, or partial matching or even synonyms matching.

Comment: For now I'm using the basic default similarity module

Comment: This is not what I meant. I mean that you need to define better the requirements. If it helps explaining better these, use examples to indicate what should match, what not and what should be the scoring. Alternatively, you can take a look at what I attempted below and evaluate how it helps or not.

Comment: Here goes, I've indexed parts of chat conversations. Each conversation is split into context and answer, where context is the conversation so far and the answer is the response for the current context. Right now I'm querying the index using a new context, and the results are fine. I'm hoping to get better results if the word count would be taken in consideration, for example a greeting response is more reasonable at the beginning of the conversation, for a context with n words ~

Comment: @AndreiStefan, Thanks for your help ... say do you have any idea of what is the best way to use word2vec as synonyms tokens engine. I have found [this](http://www.slideshare.net/lucidworks/implementing-conceptual-search-in-solr-using-lsa-and-word2vec-presented-by-simon-hughes-dicecom) article, and would like to go on that path.

Comment: Hm... that looks interesting, but of course you need to implement this yourself in custom code in Elasticsearch to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query uses Groovy to look at the length of the actual text indexed into ES (using `_source.article.length()`) and at the length of the text to be searched. As a very simple basic query, I used `match_phrase` and then rescored the documents based on how long the text to search is compared to how long the original text is.

```
GET /articles/context/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "article": "this is a paragraph"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "text_to_search_length=text_to_search.length(); compared_length=_source.article.length();return (compared_length-text_to_search_length).abs()",
              "params": {
                "text_to_search": "this is a paragraph"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```